# Building a tower with a limited set of blocks

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A wizard has commanded you, the master architect, to build towers by stacking stone blocks.

You have at your disposal five stone masons of limited intellect.  Each mason is capable of making only a single type of cylindrical block, the height of which must be a positive integer, and the diameter of which is irrelevant.  The masons have sufficient time to build as many copies of their block type as will be needed.

The wizard, being capricious, will demand a tower with an integer height between 1 and 300 units.  There is no way to know in advance what height will be required; it will be selected from a uniform distribution.  The wizard has also decided that each tower be made of no more than five blocks.  Using multiple copies of the same block size is acceptable.  The blocks can't be stacked sideways.

What five integers do you assign to your masons to maximize the probability that you will be able to build a tower of the specified height, using no more than five blocks total?  What is that probability (i.e., the probability that you can meet the wizard's demands and escape an untimely death)?  Are there multiple solutions with equally good probability?  What is the best way to get good solutions quickly?

To restate more formally:

Select the set of five positive integers {a, b, c, d, e} which maximize the probability that

```
n1*a + n2*b + n3*c + n4*d + n5*e == RandomInteger[{1,300}]
n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 <= 5
```

has at least one solution, where n1 through n5 are integers >= 0.

The only strategy I could think of was randomly modifying an existing solution and checking if it was better than the current solution.  This is hardly efficient, and is likely to get stuck in some local maximum.  Maybe there's something more elegant.  Here's the Mathematica code:

```
score[{a_, b_, c_, d_, e_}] := Length[Flatten[FindInstance[{
   n1*a + n2*b + n3*c + n4*d + n5*e == #,
   n1 >= 0, n2 >= 0, n3 >= 0, n4 >= 0, n5 >= 0,
   n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 <= 5
   }, {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5}, Integers, 1] & /@ Range[300], 1]]

best = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25};
bestScore = score[best];
nRounds = 1000;

Do[
 new = best + RandomInteger[{-2, 3}, 5];
 newScore = score[new];
 If[newScore > bestScore, bestScore = newScore; best = Sort[new]];
 If[Mod[r, 10] == 0, Print[r, "  ", best, "  ", bestScore]],
 {r, 1, nRounds}
 ]
```

Comment: Did you forget to include your MM code showing some attempt? Without some, I can assure you a Wizard will be involved, and it won't have anything to do with tower building...

Comment: Since the wizard in question is assuredly a bozo, neglecting to fully specify and restrict the problem at hand, I'd have four of my masons make blocks of H*W*D of `{{1, 2, 4}, {8, 16, 32}, {64, 128, 256}, {31, 53, 93}}` respectively (only the height is mentioned in the "wizard"'s demands). That is sufficient to build every integer-height tower from 1 to 300 and well beyond, with a maximum of 4 blocks needed, with probability 1. My remaining mason will be tasked with engraving the extra blocks with "NUMNUT", to be used on the "wizard"'s tomb...

Comment: @rasher, nice solution... I was only able to get 210 different tower heights using blocks of `{1, 7, 48, 58, 73}` but anyway  I think the question is off topic.

Comment: @rasher, you're right, I failed to specify the block orientation.  I have updated the problem to disallow this trivial solution.

Comment: FWIW, `{1, 8, 19, 60, 73}` gets 211 solutions, found with a generic hill-climbing solver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to answer this directly, but I think I can help you approach it.  We can show that the upper limit to the best solution is 251 different heights, as that is the maximum number of unique sums that can be produced.  Using *Mathematica*:

```
p = {a, b, c, d, e};
Array[Tr /@ Tuples[p, #] &, 5, 1, Union] // Length
```

> ```
> 251
> ```

You could also express this as the coefficients of the expansion of: $\left(1+x^a+x^b+x^c+x^d+x^e\right)^5$ where $(a, b, c, d, e)$ are your block heights.

---

After a randomized search the best values I found were:

208 : {1,5,26,60,74}
208 : {1,8,41,53,71}
209 : {1,7,48,58,73}
209 : {1,5,26,60,74}
210 : {2,7,39,57,72}

I used this *Mathematica* code:

```
count[p_] /; Min[p] < 1 = 0;

mem : count[p_] := mem =
  -1 + Tr @ Unitize @ PadRight[
     CoefficientList[(1 + Tr["x"^p])^5, "x"], 301]

try = best = Sort @ RandomInteger[{1, 150}, 5]

Do[
  If[count[try] > count[best], Print[count[best], " : ", best = try]];
  try = Sort[best + Round @ RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 6], 5]],
  {100000}
]
```

Comment: In those terms, to make *all* heights would mean the polynomial $x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{300} = (x^{301} - 1)/(x - 1)$

Comment: Is the 'mem' variable doing some kind of memoization to reduce the number of redundant calls to the 'count' function?  I haven't encountered this syntax before.

Comment: @user2790167 Yes, expect it's a pattern name, not a variable.  Please see the bottom of [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2676/121).

Comment: @user2790167 I just realized that `Coefficient`, as I used it, is very slow.  I shall update my answer with an improved `count`.

Comment: Your code before the last edit was doing something peculiar.  It returned these two solutions:  209 : {1,8,41,59,71}    and     210 : {1,8,41,59,71}.  How can count produce different results for the same input?

Comment: @user2790167 I don't know what happened.  Perhaps my code isn't working right.  I'll try to revisit this later today, but I may not have time.

Comment: @user2790167 Yeah, and my last edit (`CoefficientList`) broke this because of negative values.  Sorry, out of time for this right now.

Comment: No worries, you've helped me quite a bit.  Thanks!

Comment: @lithiumdeuteride Thanks for the Accept.  I'm glad this was helpful, but I'm sorry that no one could give you a better analysis of the problem.

Comment: I'm convinced it must be NP-hard like the knapsack optimization problem.  Given the difficulty in finding good solutions for towers of 5 or fewer blocks selected from 5 types with a ceiling of 300, global optimization for towers of 8 or fewer blocks selected from 8 types with a ceiling of 15000 is probably totally infeasible.  The only thing I thought of to refine the approach is to allow zero-height blocks, but require exactly N blocks be used in every tower, rather than N or fewer.  Maybe that would allow more efficient code somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Solve[a n1 + b n2 + c n3 + d n4 + e n5 == RandomInteger[{1, 300}], {a,
   b, c, d, e, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5}]

> Just guessing.